# Mocking router.events.subscribe() Angular2

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, jasmine

In my app.component.ts I have the following ngOnInit function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (!e.url.includes('login')) {
          this.loggedIn = true;
        } else {
          this.loggedIn = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Currently I'm testing if the sub is not null but I want to test the function with a 100% coverage.

I want to mock the router object so that I can simulate the URL and then test if the this.loggedIn is correctly set.

How would I proceed to mock this function? I tried it but I don't know how I would take this on with the callback involved and with the NavigationEnd.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have found the answer, if someone is looking for it:

```
import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

class MockRouter {
  public ne = new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/login', 'http://localhost:4200/login');
  public events = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(this.ne);
    observer.complete();
  });
}

class MockRouterNoLogin {
  public ne = new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard', 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard');
  public events = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(this.ne);
    observer.complete();
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide info on your TestingModule Configuration.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Please provide explanation of usage.

Comment: To get this to work `provide` the mock class to the `TestBed`. `providers: [{provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter]`

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer is correct but this is a bit simpler, you can replace

```js
public ne = new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/login', 'http://localhost:4200/login');
public events = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(this.ne);
    observer.complete();
  });
```

by:

```js
public events = Observable.of( new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/login', 'http://localhost:4200/login'));
```

And find below a full test file to test the function in the question:

```js
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import {
  async,
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/core/testing';

/**
 * Load the implementations that should be tested
 */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


class MockServices {
  // Router
  public events = Observable.of( new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/login', 'http://localhost:4200/login'));
}

describe(`App`, () => {
  let comp: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  /**
   * async beforeEach
   */
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useClass: MockServices },
      ]
    })
    /**
     * Compile template and css
     */
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  /**
   * Synchronous beforeEach
   */
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    comp    = fixture.componentInstance;

    router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get( Router);

    /**
     * Trigger initial data binding
     */
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it(`should be readly initialized`, () => {
    expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
    expect(comp).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('ngOnInit() - test that this.loggedIn is initialised correctly', () => {
    expect(comp.loggedIn).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the full file. Helpful

Comment: This will trigger an exception `Unhandled Promise rejection: this.events.next is not a function ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this.events.next is not a function`.

Answer (score 16):

I created a version of the router stub from Angular docs that uses this method to implement NavigationEnd event for testing:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class RouterStub {
  public url;
  private subject = new Subject();
  public events = this.subject.asObservable();

  navigate(url: string) {
    this.url = url;
    this.triggerNavEvents(url);
  }

  triggerNavEvents(url) {
    let ne = new NavigationEnd(0, url, null);
    this.subject.next(ne);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any clue how to mock `RoutesRecognized` instead of `NavigationEnd`?

Answer (score 6):

This is a really old question but I just came across it looking for something better than what i have and in my case i need to test several different events.  My basic approach was just to change the Router.events to a non read only value like

```
 (router as any).events = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
 fixture.detectChanges();
 router.events.next(new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/login', 
 'http://localhost:4200/login'));
  expect(comp.loggedIn).toEqual(true);
```

Hope maybe that helps someone.  I couldn't find an easier solution after looking around

Answer (score 5):

- use `ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>` to mock the `router.events`
- export it to a service so that you can test it more independently from the component, and other components may also want to use this service ;)
- use `filter` instead of `instanceof`
- then add the tests for the component, I think that will be trivial right :)

## source code

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router, RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteEventService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  subscribeToRouterEventUrl(): Observable<string> {
    return this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map((event: RouterEvent) => event.url)
      );
  }
}
```

## test code

```js
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {RouteEventService} from './route-event.service';
import {NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router, RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';

describe('RouteEventService', () => {
  let service: RouteEventService;
  let routerEventReplaySubject: ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>;
  let routerMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    routerEventReplaySubject = new ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>(1);
    routerMock = {
      events: routerEventReplaySubject.asObservable()
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock}
      ]
    });    
    service = TestBed.inject(RouteEventService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('subscribeToEventUrl should return route equals to mock url on firing', () => {
    it('NavigationEnd', () => {
      const result: Observable<string> = service.subscribeToRouterEventUrl();
      const url = '/mock';

      result.subscribe((route: string) => {
        expect(route).toEqual(url);
      });

      routerEventReplaySubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, url, 'redirectUrl'));
    });

    it('NavigationStart', () => {
      const result: Observable<string> = service.subscribeToRouterEventUrl();
      const url = '/mock';

      result.subscribe((route: string) => {
        expect(route).toBeNull();
      });

      routerEventReplaySubject.next(new NavigationStart(1, url, 'imperative', null));
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous example `public events = Observable.of( new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost..'));` does not seem to work according to Karma which *complains* about:

> Failed: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'router.routerState.root')
>   rootRoute@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js

Despite (mocked) Router instance **events**' subscription callback has been running successfully in `ngOninit()` of original app.component.ts, i.e main application component under testing by Karma:

```
this.sub = this.router.events.subscribe(e => { // successful execution across Karma
```

Indeed, the way Router has been mocked sort of looks incomplete, inaccurate as a *structure* from Karma's prospective: because of `router.routerState` that turns out to be undefined at run time.

Here is how Angular Router has been "stubbed" exactly on my side, including `RoutesRecognized` **events** *articifically baked* as `Observable`s in my case:

```
class MockRouter {
    public events = Observable.of(new RoutesRecognized(2 , '/', '/',
                                  createRouterStateSnapshot()));
}

const createRouterStateSnapshot = function () {
    const routerStateSnapshot = jasmine.createSpyObj('RouterStateSnapshot', 
                                                     ['toString', 'root']);
    routerStateSnapshot.root = jasmine.createSpyObj('root', ['firstChild']);
    routerStateSnapshot.root.firstChild.data = {
        xxx: false
    };
    return <RouterStateSnapshot>routerStateSnapshot;
};
```

to fit what `ngOnInit()` body expects, requiring `RoutesRecognized` **event** with deep structure:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.router.events.filter((event) => {
        return event instanceof RoutesRecognized;
    }).subscribe((event: RoutesRecognized) => {
        // if (!event.state.root.firstChild.data.xxx) {
        // RoutesRecognized event... to be baked from specs mocking strategy
   });
}
```

Recap / summary of my <package.json> content:

> angular/router: 5.2.9,
>   karma: 2.0.2, 
>   jasmine-core: 2.6.4,
>   karma-jasmine: 1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

The [Angular Testing Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#routing-component) shows how to do this using a Jasmine spy:

```
const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigateByUrl']);
const heroServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HeroService', ['getHeroes']);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HeroService, useValue: heroServiceSpy },
    { provide: Router,      useValue: routerSpy }
  ]
})
```

...

```
it('should tell ROUTER to navigate when hero clicked', () => {

  heroClick(); // trigger click on first inner <div class="hero">

  // args passed to router.navigateByUrl() spy
  const spy = router.navigateByUrl as jasmine.Spy;
  const navArgs = spy.calls.first().args[0];

  // expecting to navigate to id of the component's first hero
  const id = comp.heroes[0].id;
  expect(navArgs).toBe('/heroes/' + id,
    'should nav to HeroDetail for first hero');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is probably this:

```
(router.events as any) = new BehaviorSubject(
      new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/plain', `http://localhost:4200/plain`)
    );
```

If you are using **Jest** for testing and you are detecting the `NavigationEnd` event of the `Router` in `ngOnInit()` of a component, make sure to run the test in the `waitForAsync()` test method.

Here is an example:

```
export class CatchPageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
        take(1) //needed to prevent infinite loop since we are triggering more navigation events in the subscription
      )
      .subscribe((navEnd) => {
        const url = new URL(navEnd.urlAfterRedirects, 'http://localhost:8080'); //base is not relevant, just to be able to create URL to parse
        const path = url.pathname;
        if ('/fancy' === path) {
          this.myService.myFunction()
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['plain']);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

```
describe('CatchPageComponent', () => {
  let component: CatchPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CatchPageComponent>;
  let myService: MyService;
  let router: Router;

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
      ],
      imports: [
        CatchPageModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [CatchPageComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CatchPageComponent);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call myService when route is fancy', waitForAsync(() => {
   //simple mock of the NavigationEnd event
    (router.events as any) = new BehaviorSubject(
      new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/fancy', `http://localhost:4200/fancy`)
    );

    const myFunctionSpy = jest.spyOn(myService, 'myFunction');

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(myFunctionSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

So I have realized `this.router.navigate(['plain']);` kept the second test hanging. If you need it in your implementation, you should mock it either in the `beforeEach()` method or in a specific test like this `jest.spyOn(router, 'navigate').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));`

Here it is:

```
  it('should redirect to plain page', waitForAsync(() => {
    jest.spyOn(router, 'navigate').mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));  //mocking navigate

    (router.events as any) = new BehaviorSubject(
      new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/plain', `http://localhost:4200/plain`)
    );

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['plain']);
  }));
```