# how to mock ActivatedRouteSnapshot?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test the following code:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {

      if (val instanceof ActivationEnd && val.snapshot) {

        this.selectedLanguageCode = val.snapshot.queryParams.lang ? val.snapshot.queryParams.lang : 'en';
        this.languageService.setLanguage(this.selectedLanguageCode);

        this.langCodeFromUrl = val.snapshot.queryParams.lang;
      }
    });

    this.setupAvailableTranslations();

  }
```

I've seen posts like the following:

[Mocking router.events.subscribe() Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475342/mocking-router-events-subscribe-angular2)

and

[Angular 6 - how to mock router.events url response in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901047/angular-6-how-to-mock-router-events-url-response-in-unit-test)

saying, "It's easy, just do this or that..." (i.e.

But essentially what I really need to do is have the test router return a fake ActivationEnd event, with a snapshot.  Have spent a fair bit of time googling and trying different techniques and wonder why it appears to be a non-trivial task.

Comment: Don't use the test router, provide your own with `useValue`; all it has to be is `{ events: of(event) }`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was as follows - changed the component to:

```
selectedLanguageCode: string;
  langCodeFromUrl: string;
  routeQueryParamMapSub: any;

  constructor(
    private languageService: LanguageService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.routeQueryParamMapSub = this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => {

      this.selectedLanguageCode = queryParams.get('lang') ? queryParams.get('lang') : 'en';
      this.languageService.setLanguage(this.selectedLanguageCode);

      this.langCodeFromUrl = queryParams.get('lang');

    });

    this.setupAvailableTranslations();

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeQueryParamMapSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

... and the test...

```
  let lang = 'en';

let testBedConfigBase = {
    imports: [
      FormsModule,
      RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
    ],
    declarations: [ HeaderComponent, MockBreadcrumbsComponent ],
    providers: [
      { provide: LanguageService, useFactory: () => { return languageService; } },
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { 
          queryParamMap: of(convertToParamMap({lang})) }
      }

    ]
  }
```